# Move All Dotfiles Out of Root Directory

Tags: configuration-files, macos-sierra, zshrc, hidden-files, dotfiles

I'm am running *macOS Sierra*, and am in the process of moving all dotfiles into one directory. I have successfully exported many environment variables for various installations (`vagrant`, `composer`, `oh-my-zsh` etc) that allow me to install to a sub-directory of my choice.

Unfortunately, programs like `npm`, `subversion`, `homestead`, `git`, and others do not offer such configurations.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It is a _very_ long standing unix convention (3 or 4 decades) that programs expect a configuration file or directory in `$HOME/.<program>`. Trying to subvert this is pushing a big stone uphill for no immediately obvious benefit.

Comment: @NormanGray Today, there are far more programs than before, completely bloating the `$HOME` directory. I want to keep all my settings and configurations in source control.

Comment: I'd agree that keeping these files in source control is a reasonable goal. `rcs` might be the right tool for that, since it stores revisions 'in place'. Myself, I keep a few key dotfiles in a separate repository and link to them one by one from `$HOME`. I think there's no general solution. One possibility would be to redefine `$HOME` in a shell startup script, but that won't be bulletproof and _will_ have other consequences!

Comment: @NormanGray: Instead of linking them one by one, you can use something like [homesick gem](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick). It manages the git repo, and handles links for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a [dotfiles repository](https://github.com/TheMatjaz/dotfiles), where I keep my configuration files under `git`. [The idea is not new](https://dotfiles.github.io). What I did is move them to another directory and them create a symlink to them in the home directory. It *does not clean* the home directory as you wanted, since it's the standard place for configuration files, as stated by [Norman Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375147/norman-gray), but at least you can version them and share them across machines.

Example:

```
cd ~
mkdir dotfiles
mv .gitconfig dotfiles/.gitconfig
ln -s ~/dotfiles/.gitconfig ~/.gitconfig
```

Comment: I recently found an article that does exactly this: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski The article you linked is useful, but I believe the approach is different from @Matjaž's. Correct me if I'm wrong, but in your linked article, the `.cfg` file has set as its `--work-tree` the `$HOME` directory, where as in @Matjaž's post we're creating symlink in the `$HOME` directory to the config file where the work-tree is.

Answer (score 3):

Check out stow. That's what I use.

I have a ~/dotfiles/ directory which has folders in it like vim/ X/, etc.

Now for example vim/ will have a .vimrc file in it, and from `~/dotfiles` I can run `stow vim/` and it will automatically manage the symlinks to the home directory.

I can also run

```
cd ~/dotfiles
for folder in ./
  do [[ -d $folder ]] && stow -R $folder
done
```

To update all my dotfiles (the -R deletes old symlinks that don't exist anymore)

There is a good introduction here: http://brandon.invergo.net/news/2012-05-26-using-gnu-stow-to-manage-your-dotfiles.html